# Format align using a variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, format, alignment

I'm trying to right align some text, with a variable alignment.

For instance this works:

```
>>> print '{:>10}'.format('foo')
       foo
```

But this does not:

```
>>> x = 10
>>> print '{:>x}'.format('foo')
```

Comment: You could use `print ('{:>'+str(x)+'}').format('foo')`, although that looks really ugly.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Check [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec):

You are looking for:

```
>>> print '{0:>{x}}'.format('foo', x=x)
       foo
```

Comment: rjust() is for that

Comment: This format is better is it can be used with the new f-strings.

Comment: A note: since python 3.6 you should not be using .format anymore - use f"" - that's faster and more readable

Answer (score 1):

python has rjust() that returns text right aligned
additionally you provide it with parameters: width, fillchar; example:

```
a = 10
print str(a).rjust(20)
```