# str.format() with both alignment {:>} and variable interpolation

Tags: python, formatting, interpolation, string-interpolation

I am still trying to understand the new syntax for string formatting in Python.

```
"{fpath:>80}".format(fpath=path, flongest=longest)
```

The above code interpolates the path argument, and formats the string correctly, but replacing the text window value (80) with a variable gives 
ValueError: Invalid format specifier

```
"{fpath:>flongest}".format(fpath=path, flongest=longest)
```

How can the window size be assigned through a variable?

```
"{fpath:>???}".format(fpath=path, flongest=longest)
```

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/42558817/825190

Answer (score 4):

Okay, finally got it. The var 'longest' can be a string version of a number ('80') or an int (80). The trick is using curly brackets around only the right interpolated var.

```
"{fpath:>{flong}}".format(fpath=path, flong=longest)
```

Comment: If anyone knows of a good tutorial for f-strings covering this topic comprehensively or at least with lots of examples please post a link. It would be helpful--thanks!

Comment: That's a `.format` string, not an f-string, although the syntax is almost identical. Using a Python 3.6+ f-string, the equivalent is `f"{path:>{longest}}"`. So no method call, and we plug in the variable names directly, rather than using keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
longest='{0}.format(variable value)'#let say 80
print('{fpath:>{flong}}'.format(fpath=path,flong=longest))
```

the variable length also needed to be converted into format specifier. I hope you understand. If still there is any problem then please let me know.

Comment: A quick ipython session shows that longest can be a str or int without needing to be converted to a format specifier. So I think the first line in this answer is not needed. `print('{fpath:>{flong}}'.format(fpath=path,flong='40'))` or `print('{fpath:>{flong}}'.format(fpath=path,flong=40))` both generate the formatted string correctly.